# show tooltip only when checkbox is ng-disabled (angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I currently have a checkbox which is ng-disabled by a scope variable. When the scope-variable is true the box remains disabled and when the scope-variable is false the box remains enabled, i need to show a tooltip when it is disabled and gone when it becomes enabled in angular.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)/[`ng-hide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) to toggle the status of the tooltip.

Say, your flag is `$scope.checked`, control the tooltip like:

```
<div tooltip ng-show="checked"></div>
```